# Slim 3 framework - RenderView

Tags: php, twig, slim

I would like to render view and return it with JSON in my controler like the renderView in Symfony.

```
//use Slim\Container;
protected $ci;

    public function __construct(Container $ci)
    {
        $this->ci = $ci;
    }
public function AnalyseFacture(Request $request, Response $response,$args){
    $db    = $this->ci->dbLeak;
    $clients = self::RecuperationFacture($db);
    $data = $this->ci->view->render($response, 'envoiefacture/resultat-ajax.twig', ['liste' => $clients]);


    return $response->withJson(['data' => $data]);
}
```

Comment: I have find a solution.
`$data = $this->ci->view->fetch('envoiefacture/resultat-ajax.twig', ['liste' => $clients]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get what you try to achive, but if you want to return the rendered content within a json response then try this:

```php
// ...

$this->ci->view->render($response, 'envoiefacture/resultat-ajax.twig', ['liste' => $clients]);

$data = (string)$response->getBody();

return $response->withJson(['data' => $data]);
```